# R Markdown / Tinytex install / mirrors / AWS EC2 Windows

Tags: amazon-ec2, r-markdown, whitelist, mirror, tinytex

I use RStudio from an AWS EC2 Windows. To get .pdf file from my rmarkdown I tried to install MiKTeX on my EC2 and faced some issue, so I decided to try the tinytex solution. I correctly installed the tinytex package but I had some trouble to install tinytex from it. For your info, following security reasons only selected websites are whitelisted. So to be able to install tinytex I asked for whitelisting:

- yihui. org
- miktex. org
- ci.appveyor. com
- www.ctan. org

but I still can't get tinytex installed on my EC2 Windows. I also downloaded separetely TinyTeX.zip to install it but `tinytex:::install_windows_zip()` is not available anymore.

When I try `tinytex::install_tinytex()` I got the following error:

```
trying URL 'https://yihui.org/tinytex/TinyTeX-1.zip'
trying URL 'https://yihui.org/tinytex/TinyTeX-1.zip'
trying URL 'https://yihui.org/tinytex/TinyTeX-1.zip'
Error in xfun::download_file(..., quiet = Sys.getenv("APPVEYOR") != "") :
  No download method works (auto/wininet/wget/curl/lynx)
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In download.file(url, output, ..., method = method) :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'A connection with the server could not be established'
2: In download.file(url, output, ..., method = method) :
  URL 'https://appveyorcidatav2.blob.core.windows.net/yihui-27038/tinytex/1-0-1628/31j2ygh3xv2sk7xd/TinyTeX-1.zip?sv=2015-12-11&sr=c&sig=HJOnYMwO2zT2iFAlwT859FH53nzIHB0oV2RslIq990g%3D&st=2021-08-05T14%3A40%3A04Z&se=2021-08-05T14%3A46%3A04Z&sp=r': status was 'SSL connect error'
3: In download.file(url, output, ..., method = method) :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'A connection with the server could not be established'
```

I am not sure to understand the error message, should I ask for whitelisting another websites?

Thanks in advance for any assistance on that.

Mhd

Comment: have you also installed R package `rmarkdown`? Try reinstalling tinytext `install.packages('tinytex')`, do you get errors with JUST installing these packages? what happens when you try opening a .PDF template in Rstudio?

Comment: Hi @DanielJachetta, 


Thanks for your reply. I didn't face issue in installing `tinytex` and `rmarkdown` packages. However I faced issues in installing TinyTeX by using this command: `tinytex::install_tinytex()`. The logs I got are in my preceding message.

Comment: Just for the record, this was cross-posted at https://github.com/yihui/tinytex/issues/326